# Who gets all the token after you create an ERC20 smart contract?

Tags: erc-20, addresses

I am creating a ERC20 token, I want to know where will all of the tokens be stored. Are they all store in the address that deployed the contract?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your contract looks like.  Usually it's the creator of the contract's address

Comment: Ok. When I deploy it on the Testnet, I need to add the tokens contact to the creators address and then I get all the tokens that where created. Will it be the same way on the main net?

Comment: Yes.  I'd test on ropsten net(if that's your testnet) since it resembles the mainnet the closest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the tokens are never explicitly 'stored' anywhere. They only ever exist in the balance mapping of your ERC20 token contract.

Typically the creator of the contract is assigned to own all the tokens, but this depends on the implementation. It would also be totally fine to only 'create' the tokens when they are first time transferred to someone, for example.